# How to notify unloading of attached property to class in which it is defined?

Tags: .net, wpf, attached-properties

For one of the requirements in our silverlight project, one of my team mate has written a custom ToolTipManager. We would like to have tooltips which remains visible even after mouse is out of control/tooltip. And remove it only when user clicks somewhere else. Hence this custom ToolTipManager class.

In this class, there is a attached property ToolTipProperty for which there is OnToolTipPropertyChanged. In this event handeler the reference of control, where property is attached, is added to a private list in ToolTipManager.

```
    private static void OnToolTipPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var owner = (UIElement)d;
        var newValue = e.NewValue;
        if (newValue != null)
            // ElementsAndToolTips is dictionary.
            ElementsAndToolTips.Add(new WeakReference(owner), newValue); 
    }
```

I want to remove the reference of control from list when this control is disposed. Where can I do that. Is there any event or method like on attached property unload/detached or something like this?

P.S. Property is used in many different control, it would be good to do change in ToolTipManager class rather than many different places.

Comment: As long as the control is in `ElementsAndToolTips` list, then I don't think it will be disposed (as it's still referenced). Not trying to lead you down the wrong path, but maybe try WeakReference, and [Weak Event Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx)

Comment: @jberger We actually have added weak references to the list not the actual reference. I had put this code here like this as I thought it will be easy to understand. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: ok, so why do you want to remove reference? can't you just check `WeakReference.IsAlive`?

Comment: If you want to clean up a list of weak references, you can loop through the list once in a time and check `WeakReference.IsAlive`. If so, remove it. You can perform such clean-up i.e. every 5 times you add an item to the list. This is standard solution and often seen, when dealing with weak references.